# Почему один и тот же елемент имеет разную ширину?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так , чтобы separate был одной ширины ?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.block {
   height: 60px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: end;
   gap: 12px;
}
.block__text { 
color: white;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: end;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: 800;
   letter-spacing: -0.28px;
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), 0px 0px 2px #000, 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
.separate {
    width: 3px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #FFF;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    box-shadow:  0px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), 0px 0px 2px #000, 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
            <div class="block__text">
               Lorem
            </div>
            <div class="separate"></div>
            <div class="block__text">
               Lorem
            </div>
            <div class="separate"></div>
            <div class="block__text">
               Lorem
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Так он одной ширины

Comment: первый чуток шире , чем второй

Comment: В инспекторе оба 3х42px

Comment: просто когда я навожу мышкой на него , его что-то смешает , вот https://imgur.com/a/bFRrcaQ